# Multiplying columns in pandas without rounding error

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I need to multiply columns in pandas without rounding error (keeping totals the same).

So I have a dataframe (called combined_df) which looks like that:

```
| areaid | districtid | percent | home | job |
|  89012 | 55         | 1.0     | 70   | 20  |
| 123048 | 442        | 0.984496| 100  | 10  |
| 123048 | 34536      | 0.015504| 100  | 10  |
```

> `areaid`
>   - smaller area inside a city
>   - for example in areaid 123048: 100 people are residents and 10 people work
>
> `districtid`
>   - larger area inside a city
>   - for example `areaid` is inside two districts 442 and 34536

I need to calculate how many people are residents and going for work in each district (the result should be an integer). We can assume that people are uniformly distributed inside each area, so it's only a matter of multiplication of percent column with home/job column and then grouping by `districtid` column.

What I did:

```
def count_people(percent, people):
    return np.around(percent * people)

result = pd.DataFrame()
result['districtid'] = combined_df['districtid']
result['area_district_home'] = count_people(combined_df['percent'], combined_df['home'])
result['area_district_job'] = count_people(combined_df['percent'], combined_df['job'])
# total residents:
total_home = sum(result.groupby('districtid')['area_district_home'].sum())
```

However, if I sum all the residents they will not equal to all the residents from `areaid`. I presume that this is due to rounding error. The error will be quite small (17 ppl for a population of 19 million).

Is there a way to calculate residents and workers for each district with greater accuracy? At this point, I am not sure why I have this rounding error because if 0.984496 * 100 will be rounded to 98, then 0.015504 * 100 should be rounded to 2, and the sum will be equal.

Comment: Are you only using pandas?

Comment: Yes is there a better tool?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in round() function that takes two numeric arguments, n and ndigits, and returns the number n rounded to ndigits. The ndigits argument defaults to zero, so leaving it out results in a number rounded to an integer. As you’ll see, round() may not work quite as you expect.

Comment: Well probably i need some custom algorithm to calculate what i want, but i have no idea where to begin, a tried some custom rounding like:
`math.floor(num + 0.5)`
but it does not help.